# JSON response decoding to nil in swift

Tags: json, swift, httprequest, google-elevation-api

```
struct Jresponse: Decodable{
            //var results: [Any]
            var resolution: Int?
            var elevation:  Int?
            var location: Int?
            var lat: Int?
            var lng: Int?
        }
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?&locations=\(finalStringConvertedCoordinates)&key=\(apiKey)") else {
                    print("Error: cannot create URL")
                    return
                }
                // Create the url request
                var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                request.httpMethod = "GET"
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        print("Error: error calling GET")
                        print(error!)
                        return
                    }
                    guard let data = data else {
                        print("Error: Did not receive data")
                        return
                    }
                    guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200 ..< 299) ~= response.statusCode else {
                        print("Error: HTTP request failed")
                        return
                    }
                    do {
                        guard let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] else {
                            print("Error: Cannot convert data to JSON object")
                            return
                        }
                        guard let prettyJsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject, options: []) else {
                            print("Error: Cannot convert JSON object to Pretty JSON data")
                            return
                        }
                        guard let prettyPrintedJson = String(data: prettyJsonData, encoding: .utf8)
                        else {
                            print("Error: Could print JSON in String")
                            return
                        }
                        //print(prettyPrintedJson)
                        jsonResponse = prettyPrintedJson
                    } catch {
                        print("Error: Trying to convert JSON data to string")
                        return
                    }
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let jrData = jsonResponse.data(using: .utf8)
                    let jsonResponseProcessed = try! decoder.decode(Jresponse.self, from: jrData! )
                    print(jsonResponseProcessed)
                }.resume()
        
            }
```

the code above contains both the request and decoding of the response, I am inexperienced with JSON which may be apparent.

The issue I have is the results being returned when printing are all nil.

previously I was not using decode and instead was trying to process the data into an array where individual values could be retrieved for comparison.

The array method was producing unmanageable data as the elements where not separated in a manageable order.

like this[The nil response][1]

OUTPUT with the inclusion of print("---> data: (String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))") looks like this.

[The output can be seen here][2]

---> data: Optional("{\n   "results" : [\n      {\n         "elevation" : 11.59268283843994,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78533554077148,\n            "lng" : -122.4059982299805\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 11.68190288543701,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78538513183594,\n            "lng" : -122.4059143066406\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 11.86490249633789,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78548812866211,\n            "lng" : -122.4059143066406\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 11.53255939483643,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78533554077148,\n            "lng" : -122.4061584472656\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 11.46291351318359,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78533554077148,\n            "lng" : -122.4063262939453\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 11.69645023345947,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78558731079102,\n            "lng" : -122.4059143066406\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 11.79109859466553,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78569030761719,\n            "lng" : -122.4059143066406\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 11.35733222961426,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78533554077148,\n            "lng" : -122.4064865112305\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 11.57364559173584,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78533554077148,\n            "lng" : -122.4066467285156\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 11.7429027557373,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78578948974609,\n            "lng" : -122.4059143066406\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 12.02133083343506,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78589248657227,\n            "lng" : -122.4059143066406\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 11.66207313537598,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78533554077148,\n            "lng" : -122.4068145751953\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 11.85497093200684,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78536987304688,\n            "lng" : -122.4069137573242\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 12.22011947631836,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78599548339844,\n            "lng" : -122.4059143066406\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 12.59670543670654,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78609466552734,\n            "lng" : -122.4059143066406\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 12.19275951385498,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78546905517578,\n            "lng" : -122.4069137573242\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 12.13292598724365,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78557205200195,\n            "lng" : -122.4069137573242\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 12.98763847351074,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78619766235352,\n            "lng" : -122.4059143066406\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 13.3654317855835,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78629684448242,\n            "lng" : -122.4059143066406\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 12.14237785339355,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78567504882812,\n            "lng" : -122.4069137573242\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 12.26948738098145,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78577423095703,\n            "lng" : -122.4069137573242\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 13.74397277832031,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78633499145508,\n            "lng" : -122.4060211181641\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 14.1032075881958,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78633499145508,\n            "lng" : -122.4061889648438\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 12.31325626373291,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.7858772277832,\n            "lng" : -122.4069137573242\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 12.36202812194824,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78598022460938,\n            "lng" : -122.4069137573242\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 14.12999248504639,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78633499145508,\n            "lng" : -122.4063491821289\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 14.4321174621582,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78633499145508,\n            "lng" : -122.4065093994141\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 12.53042221069336,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78607940673828,\n            "lng" : -122.4069137573242\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 13.14097881317139,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78618240356445,\n            "lng" : -122.4069137573242\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 14.39413261413574,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78633499145508,\n            "lng" : -122.4066696166992\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 14.40865802764893,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78633499145508,\n            "lng" : -122.4068374633789\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      },\n      {\n         "elevation" : 13.98401737213135,\n         "location" : {\n            "lat" : 37.78628158569336,\n            "lng" : -122.4069137573242\n         },\n         "resolution" : 0.5964969992637634\n      }\n   ],\n   "status" : "OK"\n}\n")
Jresponse(resolution: nil, elevation: nil, location: nil, lat: nil, lng: nil)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaRZZ.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWJZX.png

Comment: We need the JSON you get after the API call

Comment: can you put this print:  
`print("---> data: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")` just after 
`guard let data = data else {....}` and show us what it prints.

Comment: It should be `decoder.decode(Jresponse.self, from: data)`, note the use of the variable `data`

Comment: thank you for your responses. Joakim I tried with data nothing changes. Workingdog  I will edit the post and add the response to it. I am still getting nil for my values in "jsonresponseprocessed"

Comment: please show the full print results as text, not half of a picture.

Comment: including those now, I added a picture due to the length of the response, apologies. results are added now to the main body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Decoding failed

The most likely reason that you cannot get any data is that your data model (here defined as a struct `Jresponse`) does not fit the actual JSON format sent back by the backend.

I've quickly check google map api doc for elevation and it seems like you should receive a json object with an array of ElevationResult at the top level. Then each result would contain the resolution, the elevation and location.

Please refer to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/overview#ElevationResult

#### Correct Data Model

```swift
struct ElevationResponse: Decodable {
    let results: [ElevationResult]
}

struct ElevationResult: Decodable {
     let elevation: Double
     let location: LatLngLiteral
     let resolution: Double?
}

struct LatLngLiteral: Decodable {
     let lat: Double
     let lng: Double
}
```

#### Change model in your decoding

```swift
let jsonResponseProcessed = try! decoder.decode(ElevationResponse.self, from: data)
```

#### Side remarks

1. The way you decode the data could be modernized and cleaner
2. Pay attention to not use force unwrap and force try
3. When posting your question, be careful to the code indentation, first select your code in Xcode and do a `ctrl + i` so that it improves its readability. Only then copy past it into your Stackoverflow question.

Comment: Thank you. this has helped me solve the problem and also improved my understanding of handling the response.

Comment: @DESWIJ Okay great, but pay attention, the resolution should be optional, otherwise you might get some error. Google API documentation is clearly specifying that.

Comment: I will be sure to keep that result as an optional. Thank you for your help. I don't have enough rep to upvote you

Comment: how can I query the resulting structure for specific indexes of say elevation as an example? I have been trying and I can get the first and last elements of the collection but nothing else.

Comment: @DESWIJ `jsonResponseProcessed.results[1].elevation`
Replace 1 by any desired index

Comment: thank you. I have been trying to achieve this since I fixed the previous issue. I am unfamiliar with json.

Answer (score 1):

as suggested by @Joakim Danielson, you should modify your code to

```
 let jsonResponseProcessed = try! decoder.decode(Jresponse.self, from: data )
```

According to google docs, at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/start

you should use this data structure: EDIT

```
struct Jresponse: Codable {
    let results: [Result]
    let status: String?
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let elevation: Double
    let location: Location
    let resolution: Double?
}

struct Location: Codable {
    let lat, lng: Double
}
```

Comment: Same opinion but the resolution is optional, decoding would fail if not present in the payload

Comment: Thank you for your help my problem is solved, I do have one question. When I access these values can I retrieve a singular item. e.g : print(JsonResponseProcessed["elevation"])

Comment: @DESWIJ If you want to access to one of the received elevation result, you can do the following:
`print(jsonResponseProcessed.results.first!.elevation)`

You can also directly access to a specified index with a regular subscript, but be careful to index out of bounds. (also you should safely unwrap, never use force unwrap it is just for the example)

Comment: updated my answer with "let status: String?" just in case it is not present. And as mentioned similarly for resolution.

Comment: If I want to access a specific item how do I go about doing that.  I have tried to get an individual element of elevation and im given the error "ElevationResponse" has no subscript"